# How to control docking order in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I'm looking for a way to control the order in which the items dock to the top of my control.

I've noticed as I add children to my control (in the designer, or through code), the newest child is always at the top. I'd like for the newer children to be on the bottom, and the oldest to be at the top.

Is there a way to do this through code? In the WinForms designer, `RightClick->Order->BringToFront` / `SendToBack` is doing something similar to what I want to do, but how can this be done programmatically?

Comment: Thank you; I needed to programmatically control the docking and I didn't even realize that their order controlled how they docked.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use these methods:

```
myControl.SendToBack();
myControl.BringToFront();
```

Comment: I was looking for `control.SendToFront()` See, now that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Tommy: Do you typically program from behind your computer? :)

Comment: On window from design, right click. select sendToBack and Right click again: BringToFont

Comment: This method also applies to adding docking controls in the form designer. With the context menu, you can send to back, then bring to front then dock and it will be the last control in the docking "chain".

Answer (score 170):

Go to View → Other windows → document outline.

In that window drag the controls so the docking is as you like it to be.

Comment: I was wondering what words I could use to describe that exact window, get there eventually on Google, Thank you!

Comment: This does not work if controls are added dynamically.

Comment: Solve my problem easily at design time.

Comment: I found out that the windows are listed in reverse order. If I just drag around components, they will parent each other, which I did not want. What I had to do what to drag controls one after another to the top of the list of controls of the same parent, in reverse order to have the components in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks. this is what i was searching for.

Comment: 8 years later... best answer

Comment: This is the one! Just drag around the order and it works perfectly, what a great tip!

Comment: This is a horrible answer. At least, for the question asked. OP asked if there was a way to do this in code...

Comment: @JustinGreywolf, look at the edit history of the Question asked. The original question didn't even mention on how to do this in code...

Comment: @Stormenet I stand corrected, thanks

Answer (score 13):

As you said, the newest control added to the controls collection is the one on top.  If you need a newer control to be added at the bottom, I'll suggest to create a list of controls, add the controls to the list, reverse the list and add the list to the controls collection.

```
List<Control> controls = new List<Control();
controls.Add(new myFirstControl());
controls.Add(new mySecondControl());
controls.Reverse();
this.Controls.AddRange(controls.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 6):

A control has two methods to achieve what you are looking for: `BringToFront` and `SendToBack`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that when doing this programmatically, then there's a very easy way to achieve this, namely:

```
containerPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(Element, 0); //sends element to the bottom of the list
```

Answer (score 4):

The order in which the controls are being added to the Controls collection determines the docking order.

Comment: I need to edit the docking order after the controls are added to the collection

Comment: Then go for the `ControlCollection.SetChildIndex(control, index)` method.

Comment: @Oliver Hanappi: Is it possible to do this in the designer? Without code?

Comment: You should be able to reorder controls in the Document Outline window (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/30/document-outline-windows-form-projects-vstiptool0118.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

(For the sake matter of showing another option):
In Visual Studio 2012 (and later):

1. Select the Control you want to Move to the Front (or back);
2. Click in the below marked buttons (Bring to Front / Send to Back);
   [image]

This will give you the possibility to rearrange the Controls to your desired order.

Answer (score -4):

Use the FlowLayoutPanel it does exactly what you want.

Comment: The answer could use more details, however a fresh take or opinion on how to organise panels doesn't need to be down-voted this hard. 

A FlowLayoutPanel or SplitLayout COULD be a nicer way to handle this. Instead of having the order controlled "behind the scenes" in a weird way by winForms.