# Visual Studio 2005 Change order of childs in a Control

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

In the designer, I have added several items (numericUpDown, labels and such) into one TabPanel. I want to align them properly from top to bottom, so I used 'dock->top'. But I can't change the order of the docked items now. 
According to [How to control docking order in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607508/how-to-control-docking-order-in-winforms) (answer near the end) the order is fixed depending on when I added the items to the control. But there must be a way to change that. Can I do that in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio go to main menu 
View / other windows / Document outline

There you can move the childs to the correct position

Comment: This answer is already given in my linked question. It is working, indeed... The first time I tried it it did not work somehow -.-